# .html extensions showing in website URL when they shouldn't

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have been trying to remove the .html file extensions from URLs in the website. This has been done by going through the webpages and removing the .html from href commands to all the other pages. This is backed up by the `.htaccess` file so it doesn't get confused by this.

When navigating though the site, for example I am on home page and I select the link to take me to "About", I arrive at the correct page but the .html extension is back again? What is also happening is when I am on a page and select that same page (navigating to the page I am already on) the page toggles between having the extension and not having it? Any ideas what going on here?

I have gone through every html code for each page and double checked all href's and there are no .htmls where there shouldn't be...

Website should you want to have a look is [www.jbeventech.co.uk](http://www.jbeventech.co.uk)

Comment: if my answer helped, please consider marking it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file your RewriteEngine to remove the .html should look like the following (or similar):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

I've just tested your problem on your [website](http://www.jbeventech.co.uk) and don't seem to have any issues seeing the .html extension on any pages.

Try to empty your cache as this may be causing the issue. You do this by pressing the shortcut:

OSX - `alt-command-e`

Windows - `ctrl + shift + del`

Comment: Never thought of that... Wouldn't be surprised if that solves it! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at your site and it appears to be working as you want. I don't see any .html in the address, just jbhome, jbabout, etc. Is there any link in particular that's causing a problem?

In the absence of using a framework or other voodoo, you can eliminate use of the file extensions in URLs by putting everything in its own directory and only having index.html (or whatever "default" directory page name you configure).